# How to remove JVM property "https.proxyHost"?

Tags: java, android, https, proxy

I was using proxy on my system for some purpose. But now I don't have any proxy set on my system as well as from the Android Studio proxy settings I have removed the proxy and set it to no proxy.

But I keep getting the following error:

> You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to .... This may lead to 
>   incorrect behavior. Proxy should be set in Settings|HTTP Proxy

As well when I try to build/sync the Gradle file without proxy server the files doesn't get compiled and says please check your network connection where I have internet connection.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If anyone still looking for the solution to the same, here is what worked for me

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DsocksProxyPort"
```

for removing http proxy ports

Source http://mxw.pl/blog/?p=4

Comment: May you please elaborate, where do i need to type this line.

Comment: i already did that. You saved my hours thanks, but after executing this line terminal didn't gave any response

Comment: It doesn't return but if no error that means it has been processed successfully

Comment: `-DsocksProxyPort`? Is that the reference article mistyped?

Comment: It's not but would suggest you to type it n the terminal rather copy pasting

Comment: ```JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DsocksProxtPort"```

Comment: Brother, you just saved me another gruelling hour. I want to send you flowers.

Comment: Make sure to restart Android Studio after making this change.

Comment: for macs @AmreshDeshpande answer is better

Comment: Hello,I was checked this link http://mxw.pl/blog/?p=4 but doesn't work .Can you explain.How can ı apply this solution?thank you.

Comment: I just restarted Android Studio and the "You have JVM property https.proxyHost set to ..." gone. Worth to try it before hours searching for where to put this command. :P

Answer (score 19):

select `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options` add below:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost
-Dhttp.proxyPort
-Dhttps.proxyHost
-Dhttps.proxyPort
-DsocksProxyHost
-DsocksProxyPort
```

Comment: This is the best answer , because only need configure once and never need to worry this problem again

Comment: And restart the IDE.

Answer (score 13):

**Using a Mac:**

Go to `Network settings -> Advanced -> Proxies` and uncheck "proxy server required password" for both HTTP and HTTPS. Remove user name and password.

In IntellJ/Android Studio restart with `File -> Invalidate and Restart -> Just Restart`

Answer (score 6):

on Mac:
goto System Preferences, Java -> open java control pan -> general -> Network Settings -> choose 'Direct Connection'
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by switching agents on and off many times. Under Mac: Open the 〜/.gradle/gradle.properties file and delete the agent configuration manually.

Comment: I had a [proxy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330895/gradle-sync-failed-connection-refused) with a fresh install of Android Studio, but this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by this solution:

**On Windows:**

Go to your **User Folder** - on Windows 7/8 this would be:

`[SYSDRIVE]:\Users\[your username]` (ex. `C:\Users\Iman\`)

In this folder there should be a folder called `.AndroidStudioBeta` or `.AndroidStudio` (notice the period at the start - so on some OSes it would be hidden).

Delete this folder (or better yet, move it to a backup location - so you can return it if something goes wrong).

This should reset your Android Studio settings to default.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac , Go to **System Settings** -> **Network** -> **Proxies**

[image]

Make sure all these (HTTP,HTTPS,SOCKS) are cleared & Off, Set proxy in your **IntellIJ**