# Error "Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proxy

So I just installed Android Studio again after a long time and it asked me to configure the proxy, so I did. I tested the connection and it worked.

Then it asked me to configure the proxy settings for Gradle and I used the same configurations.

Now, when loading the latest Vuforia Sample project, I get an error:

> Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect

I've looked everywhere on the web, but I can't find a solution. It can't be the proxy settings; I've configured Gradle just like the IDE.

Comment: If you are having this error without using a Proxy, try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`. It did the trick. (I also cleaned the project but I don't think it helped.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should configure Proxy settings in Android Studio’s menu (*File* → *Settings*). Another strategy is to configure the file `gradle.properties`.

So, add these lines at the end of `gradle.properties`, located on the app folder base.

---

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[IP ADDRESS]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=[PORT, TYPICALLY 3128]
systemProp.https.proxyUser=[USERNAME]
systemProp.https.proxyHost=[IP ADDRESS]
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=[PORT, TYPICALLY 3128]
systemProp.http.proxyUser=[USERNAME]
```

Pay attention. The passwords and other values that have special characters must have slash character such as (**\#**) and so on.

Comment: I allready did that, however it did not resolve my problem! :(

Comment: Do you restart AS ? Do you check if Cache and Invalidate were performed ?

Comment: Yes! Twice at least. How do I check that?

Comment: Go to File | Cache and Invalidate (select restart option). Can you put his `gradle.properties` and `build.gradle` here (i.e., in his question) ?

Comment: This worked for me. Updated the gradle.properties file but was still facing the issue. Reason behind was presence of special characters in password.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For me `grade.properties` had a proxy because of which the sync was failing.

Answer (score 41):

I was caught with the same issue and was trying bypass proxies on Mac.

I removed the proxy from the system level ([.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)) and [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) (gradle.properties). I had no luck!

I found Android Studio unable to bypass the proxy and finally found the proxy was cached in Gradle in the below file.

```
~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

Essentially, to make sure proxy references were muted in all **gradle.prorties**, including the Gradle cache.

[Gradle cache could be find as below (in Android view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao8yh.png)

Comment: Seems like when you set a proxy and then unset it, this file still holds the proxy values. Removed the proxy values and boom, it works like a charm after rebuilding my project!

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This file is hidden like a needle in haystack. Your answer is gold, thanks !

Answer (score 16):

I have the same problem:

> can't connect to socks proxy connection refused

Try

1. Turn off VPN
2. Menu *File* → *Invalidate Caches / Restart*

This operation can fix this problem.

Comment: In my case, even Split Tunneling other apps was affecting Android Studio. I had to turn off VPN altogether.

Answer (score 15):

This happened to me when I updated Android Studio to the latest version.

The fix was to go to menu *File* → *Settings* → *Build Execution Deployment* → *Gradle* and check *Use local Gradle distribution*.

After that, in *Gradle Home* put the location to the Gradle directory - in my case it was *C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2*.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Use `gradle.properties` file in this path and check proxy info within:

```
C:\Users\[Windows-User]\.gradle\gradle.properties
```

I solve the problem by comment proxy definitions in this file.

Commented lines:

```
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=9050
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=9050
```

`#` used for comment in `gradle files`

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem recently. I had my proxy setup OK, but Gradle could not update. After a few attempts, I noticed that the <kbd>Use HTTPS proxy</kbd> check button was not selected.

I noticed that on the HTTPS proxy dialog which pops up while Android Studio starts.

Keep in mind that you might not be able to see the **HTTPS** setup from *File* → *Settings* → *HTTP Proxy*, so it is important to do it using the pop-up proxy dialog on Android Studio start.

You also may have the **HTTPS** form filled up, but you need to select that checkbox as well (at least that worked for me).

So here are the steps I follow:

1. Invalidate caches and restart
2. Close any project opens by default on Android Studio startup
3. Select "Use **https** proxy on proxy dialog

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

1. Go to **'Gradle Scripts'**
2. Then go to **'gradle.properties'**.
3. There you will see proxy settings something like:

   *systemProp.http.proxyHost=[YOUR PROXY]*

   *systemProp.http.proxyPort=[PORT]*

   As you may see, this is for **'http'** only.
4. Just add the same for **'https'**:

   *systemProp.https.proxyHost=[YOUR PROXY]*

   *systemProp.https.proxyPort=[PORT]*

It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

**Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect**

When I got this error I used the [Charles Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Proxy) app (even though Charles Proxy was completely closed). To solve it, I just disabled SSL Proxying inside Charles Proxy.

After that I got

> Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

and

> Connection refused

To solve it, just close Charles Proxy (with disabled (stopped) SSL Proxying) and restart Android Studio or analyse traffic and exclude unnecessary hosts (`Proxy* -> *SSL Proxy Settings... -> Exclude` block). In my case it was

```
<some_digits>.cloudfront.net
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

1. commented these lines in Gradle properties

   *systemProp.https.proxyPort=41258*
   *systemProp.http.proxyHost=109.199.77.83*
   *systemProp.https.proxyHost=109.199.77.83*
   *systemProp.http.proxyPort=41258*
2. Use VPN
3. Rebuild the project

Comment: Proxy settings were on C:/users/[user]/.gradle/gradle.properties for me, and not on Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

What works for me:

- Go to file
- Invalidate cache / Restart
- Select Invalidate & Restart

It should work now.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Go to file"*? A menu by the name "File"? Opening a particular file in a text editor? Something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62954992/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Not that hard to understand. He obviously meant File menu and not opening some file in a text editor. You can't select options in a file opened in text editor.

Answer (score 2):

My case might be unique as in I got Android project code and was facing this error when trying to build it. I just removed the `proxy` properties in `gradle.properties`and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest version of the Gradle build tools in `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by putting the proxy options with `http` and `https`. Before it was just `http` and was giving an error. After I added `https`, it worked.

Comment: What do you mean by *"putting the proxy options with http and https"*? What is the end result? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45917882/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I verified that in *File* → *Settings* → *HTTP proxy*, I had checked the "no proxy" option.

Then I created an exception in my antivirus software for Android Studio, and deleted the lines of proxy configuration of my gradle.properties file. Finally, I clicked on Sync Project with Gradle files and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check and review all of these files for having proxy settings:

1. `YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/App/gradle.properties`
2. `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`
3. `~/.AndroidStudioX.Y/config/options/proxy.settings.xml`

Note: replace `X.Y` with your current Android Studio version.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and my problem was easily solved:

1. Go to menu *File* → *Settings* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings* → *HTTP Proxy*
2. On this page, select option *No Proxy*.
3. Download a VPN client.
4. Connect to one of the servers and sync the Gradle.

I hope your problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate caches and restart worked for me.

Comment: What caches? Where? How?

Comment: Goto File > Invalidate Caches > (A dialog will appear) > Click on Invalidate Caches and Restart button.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue when I downloaded the [Glide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glide_API) project and solved the issue by installing JDK 1.8.0_151 and reset the JAVA_HOME. My old JDK was 1.8.0_131, and I removed the old version.

Comment: What is "the Glide project"? What does it refer to? Can you elaborate?

Comment: OK, the OP seems to have left the building (*"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*). Can somebody else chime in?

Answer (score 0):

If there is VPN running on your computer you might have to turn it off.

Comment: Hi there Ege, I'm having the same issue and I think it's because maybe my ISP in Russia where I'm currently visiting is blocking the connection. I've tried a VPN but no luck. Is there some way to use a VPN rather than turn it off as you say?

Comment: you can try to remove proxy properties in your `gradle.properties`, then  `Invalidate Caches ` finally you can re-open your VPN and start Android Studio. Perhaps you can call your ISP and ask why the hell they are blocking your connection for this though

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, open a terminal window and hit the below command:

```
echo $proxy
```

It should return your IP address and port number.

Now check your ***gradle.properties*** of your project and set the below properties as per your login details:

```
 systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
 systemProp.http.proxyUser=<userName>
 org.gradle.parallel=true
 systemProp.http.proxyPassword=<PassWord>
 org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
 systemProp.https.proxyHost=<IP Address>
 systemProp.http.proxyHost=<Proxy Host URL>
 systemProp.https.proxyPort=<Port number form above>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Preferences* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings* → *HTTP Proxy*.

If your network needs a proxy, setup *Manual proxy configuration*.

Else, select *Auto-detect proxy settings*.

Answer (score 0):

I find when I change the option of *Preferences* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings* → *HTTP Proxy* to *Manual proxy configuration*, the Gradle properties of the project won't change, so I add:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost= myProxyHost
systemProp.http.proxyPort= myProxyPort
```

Then it runs well.

Answer (score 0):

In your *gradle.properties* file inside your app project, add the following properties (both HTTP and HTTPS):

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<proxyHost>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<proxyPort>
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<proxyHost>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<proxyPort>
```

If your network has a proxy (not defined in your system configuration), go to:

Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings* → *HTTP Proxy*.

And set up *Manual proxy configuration*. Otherwise, check *Auto-detect proxy settings*.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people suggested changing proxy settings, but that was not my problem.

At the time of writing, `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2` was recently released and I was not able to update to that from my network.

However, `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1` was available and it no longer threw that error.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing on this old post as I have also faced the same problem after updating the Android Studio to 3.5. I was not using any proxy setting in my current project, still, it was showing me connection refused error. To resolve this problem I deleted the .android and .gradle file from User folder and restarted the android studio. It helped me to rebuild the project successfully.

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution is to disable [Avast Antivirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avast_Antivirus) in my case, so if you too have an antivirus, try it or make an exception for Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever used [Shadowsocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowsocks) X-NG on Mac, (mine is version 1.7.1 (1)) and once use the Global Mode, it will automatically add the following command:

~/.gradle/gradle.propertries:

```
#Mon Nov 18 03:59:09 CST 2019
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=1086
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1086
```

[image]

When you close Shadowsocks X-NG, Android studio still use the proxy, and that is why it shows

> Gradle sync failed: Connection refused

Please comment those lines out, and rebuild the project again.

```
## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
#Mon Nov 18 03:59:09 CST 2019
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=1086
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=1086
```

Answer (score 0):

Amending the *gradle.properties* file did not work for me. What worked was manually setting the proxy in settings. Additionally, I also had to enter my user name and password for the network.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.6.1 you can set the Proxy and after that, you can change that to no proxy. If still having the same issue then follow these steps:

1. Check the Gradle location from in *Settings* → *Build, Execution* → Deployment* → *Gradle*. Find the location of Gradle in your PC.
2. Now go to that location and open the *Gradle.properties* file. In this file, you have to remove the proxy settings lines.
3. That's it. Now your project is working.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:

1. turned off firewall and antivirus software
2. deleted the `.gradle` file. Location: `C:\Users\user\.gradle`
3. restarted Android Studio
4. checked the Internet connection

P.S. There is no proxy in my system (windows 8.1)

And it worked!

Answer (score -1):

Menu *File* → *Settings...* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Gradle* → *Android Studio*.

Check *"Enable embedded Maven repository"*.

Comment: Is downloading Maven dependencies the only thing Gradle would go through your proxy for? If so, this is a good answer, but you should remove the parts that are not in English.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was because I turned on the Wi-Fi settings, but actually my laptop Internet access using a LAN cable.