# Gradle sync failed on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I know there is other topics on, but it don't work with me for both of them.
Every time i just launch my project on android Studio 2.3.2 i have this message error : 
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvEpQ.jpg)

So i decided to try here ! :)

---

New log :

```
  10:05:37,894 [ 454389]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'Mobilite test recup'. 
    2017-05-16 10:05:37,929 [ 454424]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131 
    2017-05-16 10:05:37,935 [ 454430]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131 
    2017-05-16 10:05:37,956 [ 454451]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Djava.awt.headless=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, D:\Profiles\valegoupil\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo1.gradle, --init-script, D:\Profiles\valegoupil\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle] 
    2017-05-16 10:05:40,509 [ 457004]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
    org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2-all.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:217)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:765)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:749)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:227)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:415)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:494)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:608)


[...}
    2017-05-16 10:05:40,519 [ 457014]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask -  
    2017-05-16 10:05:40,519 [ 457014]   INFO - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Connection refused: connect

    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
    2017-05-16 10:05:40,521 [ 457016]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'Mobilite test recup' failed: Connection refused: connect

    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
    2017-05-16 10:05:40,743 [ 457238]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
    2017-05-16 10:05:40,743 [ 457238]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
    2017-05-16 10:05:40,744 [ 457239]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
    2017-05-16 10:05:40,745 [ 457240]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s.
```

---

The file `build.gradle (project)`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    ext.global_compileSdkVersion = 23
    ext.global_buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
    ext.global_minSdkVersion = 15
    ext.global_targetSdkVersion = 23

    afterEvaluate {
        if (getPlugins().hasPlugin('android') ||
                getPlugins().hasPlugin('android-library')) {

            configure(android.lintOptions) {
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: sry i'm french, can you be more precise ?

Comment: post the code you have in your build.gradle (app) script

Comment: You can't post it in an answer. Please delete it and edit your question

Comment: Sry it's done Daniele !

Comment: Please provide your build.gradle(App), edit your question and add Apps gradle

Comment: Hi Raksmith i have already done that

Comment: good go on.....

Comment: ow, is there a difference between my build.gradle(in my project source) and build.gradle(app) ? if yes, where is build.gradle(app) ?

Answer (score 1):

You are working with a very old version of the build tools.

Try changing this:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'`

to this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
```

Also check for updates in Android Studio and make sure that everything is up to date.

If you are on mac go to the top bar, then **Android Studio -> Check for updates**

In windows go to **help -> Check for updates**

**Probably found a solution in [this other SO answer by DZL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42751835/6427630), see if it works:**

The fix was to go to `File/Settings/Build Execution Deployment/Gradle` and check Use local gradle distribution

After that, in `Gradle Home` put the location to the `gradle directory` - in my case it was `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2`

Comment: It don't work : always the same : 09:59 Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)     Want to see log ?

Comment: Please, and also the app related build.gradle

Comment: Daniele i made you edit (check use local gradle and put the location) : it don't works

Comment: I made your solution step by step, when i clik on "sync project with gradle files" i have the same problem : 10:36 Gradle sync started

10:36 Gradle sync failed: Connection refused: connect
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: I tried to follow the step but i don't know where "Select "Use https proxy on proxy dialog"" is ?... Rly sry