# Gradle sync failed in Android Studio for 32 bit

Tags: android, gradle

I tried install Android Studio for 32bit and it run successfully. But while synchronizing with Gradle project its showing the error like as mentioned below,

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.

Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
Required by:
    project :app > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2

> Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.31.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Connection refused: connect

Without Gradle sync i cannot proceed to design my own app.
What to do with it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle sync failed: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330895/gradle-sync-failed-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link with `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom` gives me 404 error as well.

Can you try add `jcenter()` into your `build.gradle`. Because, I can access, `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom` to see if works?

Another thing if it is networking issue, you can do some proxy setup to avoid the issue, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36331245/791609)