# Android Studio: Connect to 127.0.0.1:8118 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Tags: android-studio, proxy, deep-learning, android-gradle-plugin, dl4j

I am trying to build this project https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/master/android/DL4JIrisClassifierDemo in Android Studio, and I get:

```
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
         > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8118 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

I have tried all the options from the comments in this issue [Gradle sync failed: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330895/gradle-sync-failed-connection-refused) and I can't seem to get it working... I don't know what the problem is, I even disabled my antivirus and firewall, and I still get `Connect to 127.0.0.1:8118 [/127.0.0.1] failed`. Internet Options --> Connections --> LAN Settings does not show any proxies and additionally in Android Studio the HTTP Proxy setting is set to "no proxy", so I REALLY DON'T KNOW what else to consider as an option to make this work. Please give me your insights/thoughts/experiences on this one...

I work with Android Studio 3.3.2.

Answer (score 6):

I removed these lines from gradle.properties file and it worked for me.

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
```

Answer (score 4):

check your gradle config file at somewhere like ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
is there some configs for proxy like below:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
```

Comment: No, that was not it. I already tried this one, and it didn't function.

Answer (score 2):

I removed codes below in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=7891
systemProp.http.proxyPort=7891
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

Try File -> invalidate Caches/Restart!

Answer (score 1):

For MAC and Windows users, please go to Users folder and your username folder, then open .gradle folder. Here here you'll find **the holy bullshit garbage gradle.properties** file. Just edit and clean all content in the file. (There were so many gradle.properties file located in different places)

It worked for me.

```
#Tue Jun 07 17:07:49 KRAT 2022
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
#systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=1.1.1.1
```