# Android Studio IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml connection refused

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I'm currently developing an Android mobile app using [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native) and a combination of Android Studio for the emulators and [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code).

It's all been working fine until I installed a package called *react-native-contacts*.  I've followed the instructions from this link:

*[React Native Contacts](https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts)*

Now when I run `npx react-native run-android` I get the following:

```
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I can access these files by pasting the URL into a browser.

On Android Studio, the *Http Proxy* is set to *Auto-detect proxy settings* with an *Automatic proxy configuration URL* of *http://proxy:8083*.  I didn't set these values; they were there when I installed.

Based on advice elsewhere, I've also gone into Android SDK → *SDK Update Sites* and ticked "force https:// sources to be fected using http://", but nothing seems to work.

How can I fix this issue?

<sub>I realise there's been a few questions on this already, but they seem to be from several years ago and referencing old technologies, so I don't think this is a duplicate.</sub>

Comment: Related: *[Gradle sync failed: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330895/)*

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to follow again in a React Native setup via: *[Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)*

Installing openjdk8 worked for me (I forgot to do that).

I reinstalled Android Studio and inside it I checked version updates and it updated. I saw that it updated my:

'Android SDK Platform', 'Android SDK'.