# Android Studio Gradle Sync Failed: Connection Refused

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I can't seem to figure this out.

I just opened Android Studio again after a long time of inactivity. Reinstalled the sdk, ndk and build tools. But now the gradle build is failing.

The following output is in the build log:

```
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Failed to download any source lists!
IO exception while downloading manifest:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:515)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:513)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:512)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:553)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:292)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:247)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:624)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:547)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyDownloader.downloadAndStream(LegacyDownloader.java:61)
    at com.android.repository.impl.downloader.LocalFileAwareDownloader.downloadAndStream(LocalFileAwareDownloader.java:51)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.lambda$fetchPackages$0(RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
```

I've tried adjusting the proxy settings, but had no luck.

When I go to `preferences > HTTP proxy` and click `check connection`, I get `Connection successful`.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64227422/android-studio-ioexception-https-dl-google-com-android-repository-addons-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330895/gradle-sync-failed-connection-refused) questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had set **gradle.properties**

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost
```